# ChartJS changing graphs based upon Drop Down selection using switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my code to change the graph based on the drop down selection, also I'm fetching the data from HTML Tables.
All  my code is working fine but I want this to be associated with Switch Case, or any other if you can suggest.Here is the code I tried till now.

## Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```js
 var counter = 0;
    
    $("[prasora-chart-type]").each(function()
    {
    counter++;
    var tableObject = $(this);
    tableObject.after('<div style="width:400px; height:200px;"><canvas id="prasora_new_chart'+ counter +'" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></canvas></div>');
    var ctx = $("#prasora_new_chart"+ counter);
    //var ctx = document.getElementById("#prasora_new_chart"+ counter);
    var chartType = tableObject.attr('prasora-chart-type');
    
    
    switch(chartType) 
    {
        case 'line':
            {
      //CreateLineChart(ctx, tableObject);
      }
            break;
        case 'bar':
            {
      //CreateBarChart(ctx, tableObject);
      }
            break;
     case 'pie':
            {
      CreatePieChart(ctx, tableObject);
      }
            break;
        default:
            {}
    }
    
    tableObject.hide();
    });
    
    function CreateLineChart(ctx, tableObject)
    {
    
    var header = Array();
    
    tableObject.closest('table').find('th').each(function(i, v){
            header[i] = $(this).text();
    })
    
    //var idColumnIndex = header.indexOf('ID');
    var xColumnIndex = header.indexOf('XValue')+1;
    var yColumnIndex = header.indexOf('YValue')+1;
    var labelColumnIndex = header.indexOf('Label')+1;
    var toolTipColumnIndex = header.indexOf('Tooltip')+1;
    
    var xValues = [];
    var yValues = [];
    var labelValues = [];
    var toolTipValues = [];
    
    tableObject.closest('table').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function()
    {
       
    if(xColumnIndex> 0)
     xValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(xColumnIndex)+")").text());
    
    if(yColumnIndex> 0)
     yValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(yColumnIndex)+")").text());
    
    if(labelColumnIndex> 0)
     labelValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(labelColumnIndex)+")").text());
    
    if(toolTipColumnIndex> 0)
     toolTipValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(toolTipColumnIndex)+")").text());
     
    });
    
    var dataValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
       //dataValues[i].x = xValues[i];
       //dataValues[i].y = yValues[i];
       
       dataValues[i] = {x:xValues[i], y:yValues[i]};
    } 
    
    //Working fine till here.
    
    var data = {
        //labels: xValues,
        datasets: [
            {
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: dataValues,
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    };
     
     
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
      legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
        //type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    
    }
    function CreateBarChart(ctx, tableObject)
    {
    var c = ctx[0].getContext("2d");
    
    c.font="30px Arial";
    c.fillText("Bar Chart",10,50);
    }
    
    function CreatePieChart(ctx, tableObject)
    {
    
    var header = Array();
    
    tableObject.closest('table').find('th').each(function(i, v){
            header[i] = $(this).text();
    })
    
    var valueColumnIndex = header.indexOf('Value')+1;
    var labelColumnIndex = header.indexOf('Label')+1;
    var toolTipColumnIndex = header.indexOf('Tooltip')+1;
    
    var values = [];
    var labelValues = [];
    var toolTipValues = [];
    
    tableObject.closest('table').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function(){
       
    
    if(valueColumnIndex> 0)
     values.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(valueColumnIndex)+")").text());
    
    if(labelColumnIndex> 0)
     labelValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(labelColumnIndex)+")").text());
    
    if(toolTipColumnIndex> 0)
     toolTipValues.push($(this).find("td:nth-child("+(toolTipColumnIndex)+")").text());
     
    });
    
    
    var data = {
        labels: labelValues,
        datasets: 
        [
            {
                data: values,
                backgroundColor: (values=>Please.make_color({format:"hex"})),
                hoverBackgroundColor: (values=>Please.make_color({format:"hex"}))
            }]
    };
    
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
           legend: {
                display: true           
            }
        }
    });
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tables">
    <table prasora-chart-type="bar" prasora-chart-title="State Wise Values" prasora-chart-xlabel="Performance" prasora-chart-ylabel="States"
    prasora-chart-showlegend="0" prasora-chart-varycolor="1">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Tooltip</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Maharashtra</td>
        <td>Maharashtra:20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>UP</td>
        <td>UP:40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Bihar</td>
        <td>Bihar:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Rajasthan</td>
        <td>Rajasthan:15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table prasora-chart-type="line" prasora-chart-title="State Wise Values" prasora-chart-xlabel="Performance" prasora-chart-ylabel="Indicator"
    prasora-chart-showlegend="0" prasora-chart-varycolor="1" prasora-chart-fillbelow="0" >
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>YValue</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Tooltip</th>
        <th>XValue</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Maharashtra</td>
        <td>Maharashtra:20</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>UP</td>
        <td>UP:40</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Bihar</td>
        <td>Bihar:30</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Rajasthan</td>
        <td>Rajasthan:15</td>
        <td>40</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table prasora-chart-type="pie" prasora-chart-title="State Wise Values" prasora-chart-showlegend="0" prasora-chart-varycolor="1" prasora-chart-showpercentage="1">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Tooltip</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Maharashtra</td>
        <td>Maharashtra:20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>UP</td>
        <td>UP:40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Bihar</td>
        <td>Bihar:30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Rajasthan</td>
        <td>Rajasthan:15</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="showhide(this)">
        <option value="">Chart Type:</option>
        <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
        <option value="0">line</option>
        <option value="1">bar</option>
        <option value="2">pie</option>
    </select>
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Please-compressed.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

==============================================

Comment: can you please share fiddle or codepen link ?

Comment: I haven't put it on jsfiddle, its local on my pc by now.